# Nginx tries to proxy pass to upstream name

Tags: nginx, webserver, performance-testing

Hello I have the following quite simple configuration for load balancer/fail over:

```
upstream backend_stream {
    server 192.168.0.130:8080   max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s;
    server 192.168.0.131:8080   max_fails=2 fail_timeout=30s backup;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name exmaple.com;

    # SSL stuff

    proxy_ignore_client_abort on;
    proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
    proxy_read_timeout 5s;
    proxy_send_timeout 5s;
    send_timeout 20s;
    proxy_next_upstream_timeout 60s;
    proxy_next_upstream_tries 0;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504 non_idempotent;

    proxy_pass  http://backend_stream;

    access_log /path/to/access.log vhosts_extra;
    error_log /path/to/error.log;
}
```

And the following access log format:

```
log_format vhosts_extra '$host:$server_port $remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" [$upstream_addr - $upstream_response_time] $request_time';
```

The most important is the part at the end: `[$upstream_addr - $upstream_response_time]`. I am logging which upstream server was choosen and what are the responses of upstream servers. [Nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#var_upstream_addr).

With such configuration I wanted to test what traffic can it handle. To do so I have used the Apache Benchmark command line tool to send a number of concurent requests at the time, as follow:

```
ab -T application/json -H 'Authorization: Basic XXX' -p ab_post.json -n 1000 -c 30 https://example.com
```

And my configuration is handling the requests for some time until it starts to choke (which is ok, my apps have their limits). But when the first server is starting to be overloaded and nginx has to start using the backup server something strange is happening. From time to time nginx is trying to pass the request not to the upstream server, but to the upstream name! which of course does not exist as a host. `... [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.051`

See the log fragment:

```
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:54 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.000, 3.730] 8.783
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:54 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080 - 3.843] 3.907
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:54 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.000, 3.942] 9.003
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:54 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080 - 4.044] 4.106
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:55 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.000, 4.125] 9.182
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:55 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080 - 4.249] 4.309
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:55 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.000, 4.306] 9.372
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:55 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080 - 4.410] 4.477
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:55 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.001, 4.504] 9.566
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:56 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080 - 4.583] 4.642
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:56 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.000, 4.707] 9.770
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:56 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080 - 4.798] 4.860
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:56 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 200 1183 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.000, 4.884] 9.945
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:56 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.048
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:57 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 504 176 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.000, 5.002] 10.061
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:57 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.051
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:57 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 504 176 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.130:8080, 192.168.0.131:8080 - 5.001, 5.000] 10.059
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:57 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.001, 0.000] 5.052
```

Sometimes it is trying really hard ...

```
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:58 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.002, 0.000] 5.050
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:58 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.048
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:58 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.064
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:58 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.001, 0.000] 5.065
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:59 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.001, 0.000] 5.059
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:59 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.062
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:59 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.064
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:59 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.063
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:15:59 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.066
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:16:00 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.001, 0.000] 5.051
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:16:00 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.055
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:16:00 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.001, 0.000] 5.066
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:16:00 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.057
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:16:00 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.000, 0.000] 5.032
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:16:01 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.001, 0.000] 5.001
example.com:443 12.34.12.34 - - [17/Nov/2016:16:16:01 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 502 166 "-" "ApacheBench/2.3" [192.168.0.131:8080, backend_stream - 5.002, 0.000] 5.002
```

My guess it that it is happening when all of the upstream servers are marked as "failing", but it's just a guess. I cannot find anything about such behaviour in the docs or anywhere else.

Is it normal behavior and I should just be aware that it may happen or am I doing something wrong?

The Nginx upstream [enter link description here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html)docs stands:

> If an error occurs during communication with a server, the request will be passed to the next server, and so on until all of the functioning servers will be tried. If a successful response could not be obtained from any of the servers, the client will receive the result of the communication with the last server.

The worst part is the instant `502 Bad Gateway` response.

Some environment info:

```
nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu)
```

Nginx instaled from the default package repository with all the extensions, the `nginx-extras` package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem as you, I found the answer on [this website here](http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx/2016-February/049800.html).

> Upstream name can be seen in the $upstream_addr variable if nginx 
>   wasn't able to select an upstream server to connect to because all 
>   servers were down as per max_fails/fail_timeout.  At the same time 
>   the "no live upstreams" error is logged to the error log.

I hope this could help you.